# How does this implication work?

Tags: real-analysis

I am checking my analysis homework to excercise 20.16 from Ross, Elementary Analysis. How does this implication (see picture) holds/is derived? The context of this question is epsilon-delta definition of a limit.

[image]

Comment: It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that by definition

$$|f_1(x)-L_1|<\epsilon \iff -\epsilon<f_1(x)-L_1<\epsilon \iff L_1-\epsilon<f_1(x)<L_1+\epsilon$$

therefore

$$|f_1(x)-L_1|<\epsilon \implies f_1(x)>L_1-\epsilon$$

Comment: Thats right... Thanks.

Comment: @Bright You are welcome! Bye